# Ranking Date within a subset in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am a beginner and am trying to rank by date.  I already have a filter here saying created date >=11/1/2022.  How do I rank so I can grab the earliest created date by email with the filter being applied?

```
email           created date
1@.com          11/4/2022
1@.com          1/5/2023
1@.com          2/4/2023
1@.com          2/4/2023
2@.com          1/5/2023
3@.com          1/7/2023
4@.com          12/1/2022
4@.com          7/15/2023
4@.com          5/15/2021
```

So hypothetically I want to see:

```
email           created date       Rank
1@.com          1/5/2023           1
1@.com          2/4/2023           2
1@.com          2/4/2023           2
2@.com          1/5/2023           1
3@.com          1/7/2023           1
4@.com          12/1/2022          1
4@.com          7/15/2023          3
4@.com          5/15/2023          2
```

I've tried a couple stuff I've read but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Could you add into the question your best attempt?

Comment: did you check out RANK() .... as distinct from RANKX()?

Answer (score 1):

First write a measure

```
Measure = MAX('Table'[created date])
```

Then write a measure for Rank

```
Rank = RANKX(ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[email]), [Measure],,DESC,Dense)
```

[image]